# Use of would have other than conditionals

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to know about the use of 'would have' in scenarios other than conditionals. Like, how I can use it in future, past etc. Also, if there's a casual use in British English.

Comment: "I will have money tomorrow." She said she would have money tomorrow. Not a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The only case that occurs to me is indirect speech as in "She told me last week that she would have more time for me in future".

Comment: Notice that in the conditional context it is in the form “would have *verb*” where *have* is used with the past participle of the verb to form the present perfect and past perfect. But in the non-conditional uses “have” takes its “possess” meaning.